# How do I get the modern style matplotlib plots often seen in iPython Notebook examples?

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

Take [this page](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/urls/gist.github.com/fonnesbeck/5850463/raw/1a4106474b90c773714e86c4b602152434fb6879/3.+Plotting+and+Visualization.ipynb), for example, a sample of which is posted below:

[image]

It has matplotlib examples with gray background and more subtle coloring, but when I'm running the same examples, I get the more traditionally colored plots with white background and strong colors. This also seems to be the style used in the [pandas documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/visualization.html).

How can I change the default style locally to match their style?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you read through the page you linked, just above the **Plotting in Pandas** section is the following line:

> If you want to make your plots look pretty like mine, steal the matplotlibrc file from [Huy Nguyen](http://www.huyng.com/posts/sane-color-scheme-for-matplotlib/).

In the post is a link to [this gist](https://gist.github.com/huyng/816622), which contains the `matplotlibrc` file. Make sure you read through the whole thing and customize it, as for example he has `MacOSX` as his backend, which you may want to change.

To use the file, save it as `~/.matplotlib/matplotlibrc` and restart any running instances of IPython. Your plots should now look prettier :)

Answer (score 3):

As MattDMo mentioned, using a sane `matplotlibrc` really helps.
The book "Probabilistic-Programming-and-Bayesian-Methods-for-Hackers" also uses a nice [matplotlibrc](https://github.com/CamDavidsonPilon/Probabilistic-Programming-and-Bayesian-Methods-for-Hackers/blob/master/styles/matplotlibrc). See [this](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/CamDavidsonPilon/Probabilistic-Programming-and-Bayesian-Methods-for-Hackers/blob/master/Chapter1_Introduction/Chapter1_Introduction.ipynb) for some examples.

Recently I'm using the package [`seaborn`](http://www.stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/) instead of a custom `matplotlibrc` not only because it makes my plots look great, but also because it adds some functionality for visualizing distributions, linear models and time series.